# Add string / symbol to all keys in array

Tags: php, arrays

What is the easiest way ( without looping manually ) to, in my case, prepend a dollar sign to *all* keys of an associative array?

```
$input = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'car' => 'volvo');
```

Expected output

```
array('$fruit' => 'apple', '$car' => 'volvo');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the snippet below

```
$input = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'car' => 'volvo');

$array = array_combine(
    array_map(function($k){ return '$' . $k; }, array_keys($input)), $input
);

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [$fruit] => apple
    [$car] => volvo
)
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/fHAsvU)

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop

```
$input = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'car' => 'volvo');
$output = array();


foreach($input as $key => $value) {
   $newkey = '$' . $key;
   $output[$newkey] = $value;
}

print_r($output); // should have your new keys.
```